# Any alternatives for jquery msgbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, msgbox

I am trying to include a prompt dialog in my project. Jquery Msgbox is good, but they have only allow inputs types like text, checkbox and select. I want to use textarea as I want users to leave their feedback.

Is there any jquery plugin that allows textarea prompt dialogs.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Why not use a generic modal plugin with a textarea inside it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use whatever markup you want inside a [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).